# Why does blogspot return false result on JS?

Tags: javascript, blogger

This is a [Sinhalese Transliteration Convertor](https://srilanka-information-zone.blogspot.com/p/sinhala-transliteration-to-unicode.html). It returns wrong output. Eg: If I enter **m**, it must return **ම්**, but it reruns `ම&#3530;`. I don't know why it gives additional `&#3530;` The same code is working well in [codepen](https://codepen.io/alpha2020/pen/xxGrEBx), but not in Blogspot.

The JS is

> `vowelsUni[0]='ඌ';    vowels[0]='oo';    vowelModifiersUni[0]='ූ';
> vowelsUni[1]='ඕ';    vowels[1]='o\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[1]='ෝ';
> vowelsUni[2]='ඕ';    vowels[2]='oe';    vowelModifiersUni[2]='ෝ';
> vowelsUni[3]='ආ';    vowels[3]='aa';    vowelModifiersUni[3]='ා';
> vowelsUni[4]='ආ';    vowels[4]='a\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[4]='ා';
> vowelsUni[5]='ඈ';    vowels[5]='Aa';    vowelModifiersUni[5]='ෑ';
> vowelsUni[6]='ඈ';    vowels[6]='A\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[6]='ෑ';
> vowelsUni[7]='ඈ';    vowels[7]='ae';    vowelModifiersUni[7]='ෑ';
> vowelsUni[8]='ඊ';    vowels[8]='ii';    vowelModifiersUni[8]='ී';
> vowelsUni[9]='ඊ';    vowels[9]='i\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[9]='ී';
> vowelsUni[10]='ඊ';    vowels[10]='ie';    vowelModifiersUni[10]='ී';
> vowelsUni[11]='ඊ';    vowels[11]='ee';    vowelModifiersUni[11]='ී';
> vowelsUni[12]='ඒ';    vowels[12]='ea';    vowelModifiersUni[12]='ේ';
> vowelsUni[13]='ඒ';    vowels[13]='e\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[13]='ේ';
> vowelsUni[14]='ඒ';    vowels[14]='ei';    vowelModifiersUni[14]='ේ';
> vowelsUni[15]='ඌ';    vowels[15]='uu';    vowelModifiersUni[15]='ූ';
> vowelsUni[16]='ඌ';    vowels[16]='u\\)';    vowelModifiersUni[16]='ූ';
> vowelsUni[17]='ඖ';    vowels[17]='au';    vowelModifiersUni[17]='ෞ';
> vowelsUni[18]='ඇ';    vowels[18]='/\a';    vowelModifiersUni[18]='ැ';
>
> vowelsUni[19]='අ';    vowels[19]='a';    vowelModifiersUni[19]='';
> vowelsUni[20]='ඇ';    vowels[20]='A';    vowelModifiersUni[20]='ැ';
> vowelsUni[21]='ඉ';    vowels[21]='i';    vowelModifiersUni[21]='ි';
> vowelsUni[22]='එ';    vowels[22]='e';    vowelModifiersUni[22]='ෙ';
> vowelsUni[23]='උ';    vowels[23]='u';    vowelModifiersUni[23]='ු';
> vowelsUni[24]='ඔ';    vowels[24]='o';    vowelModifiersUni[24]='ො';
> vowelsUni[25]='ඓ';    vowels[25]='I';    vowelModifiersUni[25]='ෛ';
> nVowels=26;
>
> specialConsonantsUni[0]='ං'; specialConsonants[0]=/\\n/g;
> specialConsonantsUni[1]='ඃ'; specialConsonants[1]=/\\h/g;
> specialConsonantsUni[2]='ඞ'; specialConsonants[2]=/\\N/g;
> specialConsonantsUni[3]='ඍ'; specialConsonants[3]=/\\R/g;
> //special characher Repaya
> specialConsonantsUni[4]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[4]=/R/g;
> specialConsonantsUni[5]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[5]=/\\r/g;
>
> consonantsUni[0]='ඬ'; consonants[0]='nnd';
> consonantsUni[1]='ඳ'; consonants[1]='nndh';
> consonantsUni[2]='ඟ'; consonants[2]='nng';
> consonantsUni[3]='ථ'; consonants[3]='Th';
> consonantsUni[4]='ධ'; consonants[4]='Dh';
> consonantsUni[5]='ඝ'; consonants[5]='gh';
> consonantsUni[6]='ඡ'; consonants[6]='Ch';
> consonantsUni[7]='ඵ'; consonants[7]='ph';
> consonantsUni[8]='භ'; consonants[8]='bh';
> consonantsUni[9]='ශ'; consonants[9]='sh';
> consonantsUni[10]='ෂ'; consonants[10]='Sh';
> consonantsUni[11]='ඥ'; consonants[11]='GN';
> consonantsUni[12]='ඤ'; consonants[12]='KN';
> consonantsUni[13]='ළු'; consonants[13]='Lu';
> consonantsUni[14]='ද'; consonants[14]='dh';
> consonantsUni[15]='ච'; consonants[15]='ch';
> consonantsUni[16]='ඛ'; consonants[16]='kh';
> consonantsUni[17]='ත'; consonants[17]='th';
>
> consonantsUni[18]='ට'; consonants[18]='t';
> consonantsUni[19]='ක'; consonants[19]='k';    
> consonantsUni[20]='ඩ'; consonants[20]='d';
> consonantsUni[21]='න'; consonants[21]='n';
> consonantsUni[22]='ප'; consonants[22]='p';
> consonantsUni[23]='බ'; consonants[23]='b';
> consonantsUni[24]='ම'; consonants[24]='m';   
> consonantsUni[25]='‍ය'; consonants[25]='\\u005C' + 'y';
> consonantsUni[26]='‍ය'; consonants[26]='Y';
> consonantsUni[27]='ය'; consonants[27]='y';
> consonantsUni[28]='ජ'; consonants[28]='j';
> consonantsUni[29]='ල'; consonants[29]='l';
> consonantsUni[30]='ව'; consonants[30]='v';
> consonantsUni[31]='ව'; consonants[31]='w';
> consonantsUni[32]='ස'; consonants[32]='s';
> consonantsUni[33]='හ'; consonants[33]='h';
> consonantsUni[34]='ණ'; consonants[34]='N';
> consonantsUni[35]='ළ'; consonants[35]='L';
> consonantsUni[36]='ඛ'; consonants[36]='K';
> consonantsUni[37]='ඝ'; consonants[37]='G';
> consonantsUni[38]='ඨ'; consonants[38]='T';
> consonantsUni[39]='ඪ'; consonants[39]='D';
> consonantsUni[40]='ඵ'; consonants[40]='P';
> consonantsUni[41]='ඹ'; consonants[41]='B';
> consonantsUni[42]='ෆ'; consonants[42]='f';
> consonantsUni[43]='ඣ'; consonants[43]='q';
> consonantsUni[44]='ග'; consonants[44]='g';
> //last because we need to ommit this in dealing with Rakaransha
> consonantsUni[45]='ර'; consonants[45]='r';
>
> specialCharUni[0]='ෲ'; specialChar[0]='ruu';
> specialCharUni[1]='ෘ'; specialChar[1]='ru';
> //specialCharUni[2]='්‍ර'; specialChar[2]='ra';`
>
>   
>   function startText() {
>       var s,r,v;
>       text = document.txtBox.box1.value;  
>       //special consonents
>       for (var i=0; i`//consonents + HAL
> for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
>     r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
>     text = text.replace(r, consonantsUni[i]+"්");
> }
>
> //vowels
> for (var i=0; i<vowels.length; i++){
>     r = new RegExp(vowels[i], "g");
>     text = text.replace(r, vowelsUni[i]);
> }
>
> document.txtBox.box2.value=text; }`
>
>   
>   //  End -->

```
<body onload="javascript:txtBox.box1.focus();">
<table width="100%" border="0"><form name="txtBox" id="txtBox">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                            <em>Input</em></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td width="100%"><textarea onkeyup="startText();" onselect="startText();" onclick="startText();" style="font-size: 12pt; width: 100%;" name="box1" rows="8"></textarea>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" style="position: relative; center: width: 100px;"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><em>Sinhala Unicode</em></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><textarea name="box2" rows="8" readonly="readonly" style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Potha, Malithi Web , Arial Unicode MS; width: 100%;"></textarea></td>

                          </tr>

                          </form>
                        </table>
                        <p><strong>

</body>
```

Please check both links; one on blogspot and another on codepen. Two links are given above in 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
    r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
    text = text.replace(r, consonantsUni[i]+"්");
}
```

The problem is at **"්"** at the end of this for loop.
The browser translates this emoji to a character entity code (in this case it's `&#3530;` <-- If I were to type this not in a code block, ් is what it looks like).

This can be fixed by using the [String.fromCharCode()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp) method in Javascript.
This is what you should use instead:

```
for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
    r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
    text = text.replace(r, consonantsUni[i] + String.fromCharCode(3530));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That is, of course, if you even need to add that character at the end. Otherwise you could just simply get rid of the character itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but when I type "ammaa", again an error. Do I want to change in all consonantsUni[i]+ ?

Comment: Yay! And yes, change for all consonantsUni[i]+ String.fromCharCode(_charcode_) and it should work.